# Parse: How do I create a Pointer data with PHP SDK?

Tags: php, pointers, parse-platform

The examples shown here (https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#onetomany-pointers) is in iOS and Android.

Is it possible to create a `Pointer` data store with PHP SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue trying to make a many-to-many relation and after some trial and error I got it working by doing:

```
$obj = new ParseObject("ObjectClassName");
$obj->setAssociativeArray("relationFieldName", array('__type' => 'Pointer', 'className' => 'relationClassName', 'objectId' => 'relationObjId'));
```

For example, if you want to relate a Book with a User via the Book's *authors* key, ObjectClassName would be *Book*, relationFieldName would be *authors* and relationClassName would be *_User* (remember Parse's special classes are prefixed with an underscore).

Let me know if this works for you too! It's a bit frustrating that I couldn't find anything about this on [Parse's PHP documentation on relations](https://parse.com/docs/php/guide#objects-relational-data). I had the same issue in JS before but at least [this question](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-query-for-class-with-pointer-equal-to-a-string-value) helped me right away.

Comment: I can confirm this works.
Bit annoying there is no documentation for this (or, at least, I couldn't find any either).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. There is a function in the SDK specifically for this that is more concise.

In \Parse\ParseOject:

```
$pointer =  ParseObject::create('className', $id, true);
```

I found it in ParseObject.php :

```
/**
 * Static method which returns a new Parse Object for a given class
 * Optionally creates a pointer object if the objectId is provided.
 *
 * @param string $className Class Name for data on Parse.
 * @param string $objectId  Unique identifier for existing object.
 * @param bool   $isPointer If the object is a pointer.
 *
 * @return ParseObject
 */
public static function create($className, $objectId = null, $isPointer = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to create a 1-many relationship. You can do this using `ParseObject::getRelation`, which will return an existing relation, or, create a new one (you can check out the definition [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseObject.php#L1260)).

```
$obj = new ParseObject("ObjectClassName");

// get a relation (new or existing)
$relation = $obj->getRelation('myObjects');

// add objects to this relation
$relation->add([$myObject1, $myObject2, $myObject3]);

// save my object & my relation, with the new objects in it
$obj->save();
```

If you're trying to do many-many relations you'll want to create a Join table (technically a join 'class', like `MyParseJoinClass`) instead. If I misunderstood, and you're trying to perform a 1-1, you can always set an object as a property to automatically create a pointer

```
$obj->set('myPointer', $myPointedObject);
```

Internally you can use `$obj->_toPointer` to get an array composing a pointer referencing an object, but I would recommend you utilize the supported relation & pointer types in `ParseObject` instead, much easier to manage.