# Parse PHP saving an array of pointers

Tags: php, parse-platform

I may be missing something simple but I thought I would ask here since I was unable to find any information on the subject of saving an array of pointers with the parse php sdk.

I have a list of object id's from the Groups Class, and I want to save those object id's as an array of pointers to my Organization class.

```
  try {
    $query = new ParseQuery("Organization");
    $query->equalTo('objectId', $objectID);
    $results = $query->first($useMasterKey = true);

    $groups = ParseObject::create('Organization', $data, true);
    $groups->set("test1" , $groups);
    $groups->save($useMasterKey = true);

    $results->setArray("groups", $data);
    //$results->setArray("test1", array('__type' => 'Pointer', 'className' => 'Group', 'objectId' => $data[0]));
    //$results->setAssociativeArray("test1", array($groups[0]));
    $results->save($useMasterKey = true);
  } catch (\Exception $e){
     print("An error has occurred with code: " . $e->getMessage());
  }
```

$data is an array of object group object ID's

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31637825/2124535

Comment: that doesn't do it.. it tries to create a pointer, when the type is array.. We are able to do this with the iOS client, and the output in the array type column looks like this.. `[
  {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Comment",
    "objectId": "5JbTj2k7hx"
  },
  {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Comment",
    "objectId": "oo69vxrQG0"
  }
]`  Note this is for another collection but im trying to repo this now with the parse php sdk for groups associated with an org.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is how I ended up doing it if someone else runs into this situation.

Looking over the iOS app that we have that creates similar output in the database this functionality

`Comment(withoutDataWithObjectId: aPossibleObjectIdString)`

Helps create an array of what looks like Pointers.

`[
  {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Group",
    "objectId": "5JbTj2k7hx"
  },
  {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Group",
    "objectId": "oo69vxrQG0"
  }
]`

This was just pasted from the database.  It allows the client to pull things in as a pointer somehow..

Honestly I'm not sure this is the best way to do this but what I ended up using.

```
  // HACK to add pointer type data into array type column.
  // Value is the objectID from the groups collection.
  foreach($data as $value) {
    $groups[] = array(
      "__type" => "Pointer",
      "className" => "Group",
      "objectId" => $value
    ); 
  }

  try {
    $query = new ParseQuery("Organization");
    $query->equalTo('objectId', $objectID);
    $results = $query->first($useMasterKey = true);
    $results->setArray("groupPointer", $groups);  // actual data that was generated ..   
    $results->setArray("groups", $data);
    $results->save($useMasterKey = true);
  } catch (\Exception $e){
     print("An error has occurred with code: " . $e->getMessage());
  }
```